# how to customize product zoom feature in standard magento ce 1.9.2?

Tags: function, magento, zooming, customization

I would like to do some customization in product zoom feature of standard magento ce 1.9.2.1

I see elevatezoom subfolder in the js folder of rwd default theme, and there is jquery.elevatezoom.js file which contain configuration options near the end of the file as below:

```
enter code here
......
$.fn.elevateZoom.options = {
        zoomActivation: "hover", // Can also be click (PLACEHOLDER FOR NEXT VERSION)
zoomEnabled: true, //false disables zoomwindow from showing
preloading: 1, //by default, load all the images, if 0, then only load   images after activated (PLACEHOLDER FOR NEXT VERSION)
zoomLevel: 1, //default zoom level of image
scrollZoom: true, //allow zoom on mousewheel, true to activate
scrollZoomIncrement: 0.1,  //steps of the scrollzoom
minZoomLevel: false,
maxZoomLevel: false,
easing: true,
easingAmount: 12,
lensSize: 100,
zoomWindowWidth: 300,
zoomWindowHeight: 400,
zoomWindowOffetx: 10,
zoomWindowOffety: 0,
zoomWindowPosition: 1,
zoomWindowBgColour: "#fff",
lensFadeIn: 500,
lensFadeOut: 500,
debug: false,
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
zoomWindowAlwaysShow: false,
zoomTintFadeIn: false,
zoomTintFadeOut: false,
borderSize: 4,
showLens: true,
borderColour: "#888",
lensBorderSize: 1,
lensBorderColour: "#000",
lensShape: "square", //can be "round"
zoomType: "window", //window is default,  also "lens" available -
           containLensZoom: false,
lensColour: "white", //colour of the lens background
lensOpacity: 0.4, //opacity of the lens
lenszoom: false,
tint: false, //enable the tinting
tintColour: "#333", //default tint color, can be anything, red, #ccc, rgb(0,0,0)
tintOpacity: 0.4, //opacity of the tint
gallery: false,
galleryActiveClass: "zoomGalleryActive",
imageCrossfade: false,
constrainType: false,  //width or height
constrainSize: false,  //in pixels the dimensions you want to constrain on
loadingIcon: false, //http://www.example.com/spinner.gif
cursor:"default", // user should set to what they want the cursor as, if they have set a click function
responsive:true,
onComplete: $.noop,
onZoomedImageLoaded: function() {},
onImageSwap: $.noop,
onImageSwapComplete: $.noop
;

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

I did some changes in the option parameter such as lenSize, zoomWindowHeight etc..but there is no effect in the zoom function.

Then i modify the app.js file in the js folder, creating var zoomOptions {...} then pass the zoomOptions into   image.elevatezoom() as code snipet below:

```
enter code here

// ==============================================
// PDP - image zoom - needs to be available outside document.ready scope
// ==============================================

var ProductMediaManager = {
    IMAGE_ZOOM_THRESHOLD: 20,
    imageWrapper: null,

    destroyZoom: function() {
    $j('.zoomContainer').remove();
    $j('.product-image-gallery .gallery-image').removeData('elevateZoom');
},

var ZoomOptions = {
    // set tint background
    tint:true,
    tintColour:'#F90',
    tintOpacity:0.5,

    // Size
    lensSize: 100,
    zoomWindowHeight: 300,
    zoomWindowWidth: 400,
    borderSize: 0,

    // Position
    zoomWindowOffetx: 10,
    zoomWindowOffety: 0,

    // Additional settings for Zoomer positioning.
    // zoomWindowPosition: 1,
    // zoomType: "inner",

    // Fade-in speed settings
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
    lensFadeIn: 500,
    lensFadeOut: 500,

    // Ability to zoom by using the mouse scroll.
    scrollZoom : true,

    // inertia - my favorite one 
    easing: true
```

},

```
createZoom: function(image) {
    // Destroy since zoom shouldn't be enabled under certain conditions
    ProductMediaManager.destroyZoom();

    if(
        // Don't use zoom on devices where touch has been used
        PointerManager.getPointer() == PointerManager.TOUCH_POINTER_TYPE
        // Don't use zoom when screen is small, or else zoom window shows outside body
        || Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:" + bp.medium + "px)")
    ) {
        return; // zoom not enabled
    }

    if(image.length <= 0) { //no image found
        return;
    }

    if(image[0].naturalWidth && image[0].naturalHeight) {
        var widthDiff = image[0].naturalWidth - image.width() - ProductMediaManager.IMAGE_ZOOM_THRESHOLD;
        var heightDiff = image[0].naturalHeight - image.height() - ProductMediaManager.IMAGE_ZOOM_THRESHOLD;

        if(widthDiff < 0 && heightDiff < 0) {
            //image not big enough

            image.parents('.product-image').removeClass('zoom-available');

            return;
        } else {
            image.parents('.product-image').addClass('zoom-available');
        }
    }

    image.elevateZoom(ZoomOptions);
},
```

......

The result then the zoom not functioning at all.

Please somebody help, how to get this zoom config parameter get rightly passed and result expected modification.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This an old question but in case someone else comes later...

This can be done by creating a new JS file with the following content (adapt it with your desired options):

```
var zoomOptions = {
    zoomWindowWidth: 420,
    zoomWindowHeight: 365,
    zoomWindowPosition: 3
};
for (var attrname in zoomOptions) {
    $j.fn.elevateZoom.options[attrname] = zoomOptions[attrname];
}
```

And this file should be added to the layout (local.xml for ex):

```
<catalog_product_view>
    [...]
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/zoomconfig.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    [...]
</catalog_product_view>
```

Make sure your `zoomconfig.js` file is loaded after ElevateZoom JS file.

This way, default ElevateZoom options will be override with yours.

And this is a correct way, because none of Magento file is modified.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses Minimized Javascript, so you have to edit this file instead:
./skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js